# GPS tracking solution

Tags: android, iphone, windows-mobile, gps

I want to any one give me information about GPS tracking sites that uses GPS devices for tracking vehicle movements.
server connect to devices and get location information or devices connect to server and send location information?
i want information about sites functionality for tracking vehicles location for example http://gpstrackit.com/ or http://www.gofleet.ca
i want to simulate gps devices functionality on android, Iphone, windows mobile!

Comment: I didn't really see a question there, just a request for information gathering. Do some research!

Comment: Devices must send info to server. The other direction does not work because of firewalls & other network config out of user reach.

Comment: @Liam George Betsworth: my question is which of server or device connect to other one to collect location information?

Comment: @zapl: for android can we connect to device with mqtt?

Comment: I want to get scenario about collect vehicle location in sites like http://www.gofleet.ca or http://gpstrackit.com/

Comment: You can get real time data for a specific vehicle using web services, some companies support this feature see highpointgps.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is:-

> Should the server ask the device where it is? Or should the device tell the server where it is?

The answer is, the device (client) should tell the server (web server) where it is. This type of system is very easy to implement.

The client would most likely send a `GET` or `POST` request to the server with variables detailing it's location.

An example URL using `GET`:-

> http://www.example.com/setClientLocation.php?clientID=3&latitude=51.45346&longitude=-3.85234

Answer (score 1):

The german company [GPSoverIP GmbH](http://www.gpsoverip.de/) provides software and hardware for that purpose. They also have an [iPhone App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gps-explorer/id334398785?mt=8) with many features. There are also developer API's for third party applications available.

I'm the developer of that App. Please contact GPSoverIP if you want to know more!

Comment: Thanks i want to write application for my university project that perhaps this application being Commercial in future!.But i don't know which scenario occurs in these sites to implement them on my application!.Can you give me the scenario of these applications?

Comment: In this applications server connect to device to get information or device connect to server and send information.At this time i want to write application for android devices and server application that show fleet location on web application but i don't know which of these applications connect to other one to get information!.Please help me about this

Comment: your iphone application send data to web server or server collect location information from iphone client app?Can you give me information about this mechanism

Comment: GPSoverIP has a client-server-architecture. There is a common gateway which devices can connect to (using a custom network protocol). The iPhone app basically connects to the server and requests the data over HTTP.

Comment: phix23 thank you for give information